# andEngine Box2D DrawingShapes

Tags: android, box2d, andengine, physics

Currently making a scene where users click to add shaped to the scene but I can't find a way to draw shapes such as circles and triangles so that they can be used with Box2D.
Please can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: If I understand correctly, it seems like you could just create Sprites with different shapes (by using png's of the shapes you want) and then register them to a body with a physics connector. Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the static PhysicsFactory.create and see what method you can use. CreateBoxBody, createLineBody and much more.

You can do better shapes using chains. Read some net guides if you want. But for complicated shapes there are generators which take your png file and create proper shape which you can use in your code.